# SSIS Variable Expression Unexpected Results

Tags: ssis, ssis-2008

I am writing a utility on SSIS 2008 that will check what day of the week it is and get the date for next Friday. This is what I have for a conditional if the current day of week is Wednesday.

```
DATEPART("dw",GETDATE())==4?DATEADD("dd", (DATEDIFF("dd",GETDATE() , GETDATE()) / 7) * 7 + 9, GETDATE())
```

The DATEADD portion is working when I take the `?` operator out. Am I missing something?

Here is the error I am receiving

```
Expression cannot be evaluated
Attempt to parse the expression failed. 
The expression might contain an invalid token, an incomplete token, or an invalid element. 
It might not be well-formed, or might be missing part of a required element such as a 
parenthesis.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we're talking about the SSIS Expression language here (given the double quotes, I think that's a safe assumption)

The [SSIS Expression language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/integration-services-ssis-expressions?view=sql-server-ver15) uses the ternary operator `? :` but that's not what you're doing. You're mixing `?` with `,`

```
DATEPART("dw",GETDATE())==4?DATEADD("dd", (DATEDIFF("dd",GETDATE() , GETDATE()) / 7) * 7 + 9, GETDATE()) : GETDATE()
```

Comment: I'm trying to get the date returned from DATEADD, the commas were used in the DATEADD and DATEDIFF functions. Everything to the right of DATEADD is surrounded by parentheses.

Comment: That's what I get for parsing by eye. Hold on while I spin up SSDT but my guess is that you're still needing _something_ to balance out the `?`

Comment: What you suggested was actually somewhat correct, it looks like I needed a GETDATE() on the right of the whole DATEADD statement. If you update your answer to reflect that I will mark it as correct. Thank you!

Comment: Done. Although, depending on your usage, this will keep the time component for "next Friday" so my computer evaluated it as `6/12/2020 12:14:37 PM`

Comment: That will work for my usage. It is going to be ran 8am locally every weekday and parsing the date for next Friday as the end of a date range.